# Shared variables between instances

Tags: vb.net

Is there an equivalent to "#pragma data_seg" in VB.NET?

I need to share variables, arrays between instances without IPC.

Comment: Between instances of what? A class?

Comment: Instances of the same application

Comment: You can't do so without IPC. Memory-Mapped Files are also a type of IPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to what you need are [Memory-Mapped Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: In C++, it could be to create a pragma data_seg, is there any equivalent?

Comment: No, it is not. You must forget about lot of low-level things from C++, but there is nearly always some alternative like in this case.

Comment: Thank you, but what is the best way to do so in .NET?

Comment: As I mentioned above, use MEMORY-MAPPED FILES. Then any process can read/write data from this using MemoryMappedViewAccessor class.